# how to repeat a group in regexp?

Tags: python, regex

I have a problem in my python code.

```
import re
page = '<ul id="talkList" class=aaaaaa <li class>First</li><li 
class>Second</li><li class>Third</li>...'
pattern = re.compile(r'<ul id="talkList".*?(<li.*?</li>)', re.S)
stories = re.findall(pattern, page)
for story in stories:
    print story
```

Now the result is:

```
<li class>First</li>
```

but I want the result is:

```
<li class>First</li>
<li class>Second</li>
<li class>Third</li>
```

I want to match the group `(<li.*?</li>)` 0 or unlimited times.

How can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [star](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) operator:

```
txt = 'abbabaa'
re.findall(r'(ab)*', txt)
```

outputs:

```
['ab', '', 'ab', '', '', '']
```

## Caution

Matching 0 or more will match empty string, I'm not sure thats what you need.

## Suggestion

if you are using `re.findall` you dont need to match all `li` elements in one results as all resulting matches will return from `findall`.

first capture the `<ul>...</ul>` block using `re.search()`.
then separate each `<li></li>` element using `re.findall()` on the resulting ul text

## Suggestion Two

use [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse html objects, its simpler than writing your own regexes to find html elements.

Comment: I'm already do that way(find ul and then find li). I wonder if there is a way to find it one time ^ ^ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Zero or More  =>  (<li.*?</li>){0,}
```

Comment: Would you like to augment this code-only answer with some explanatin? That would improve it noticeably.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use the regexp below instead.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(<li.*?</li>)', re.S)
```

This will work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for `re.findall()`:

```
  findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
    Return a list of all non-overlapping matches in the string.

    If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a
    list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
    has more than one group.

    Empty matches are included in the result.
```

Your RE has only one match in your string since there is only one `'<ul id="talkList"'` to match with. Since you have (one) group in your RE, `re.findall()` returns that group instead.

If you use just `'<li.*?</li>'` as your RE then `re.findall()` will find three matches and return all three:

```
import re
page = '<ul id="talkList" class=aaaaaa <li class>First</li><li class>Second</li><li class>Third</li>...'
pattern = re.compile(r'<li.*?</li>', re.S)
stories = re.findall(pattern, page)
for story in stories:
    print story
```

Output:

```
<li class>First</li>
<li class>Second</li>
<li class>Third</li>
```

Comment: Thank! I know if change it to `pattern = re.compile(r'<li.*?</li>', re.S)` will match all <LI>, but I just  want to match the <LI>  **UNDER** this UL(` <ul id="talkList"`) .  After your answer with the python documentation, I think I can't do that when I use re.findall() method. am I right?

Comment: See ShmulikA's suggestion about doing `re.search()` first to isolate the `<ul>...</ul>` of interest. I think that's the right idea.

Comment: OK,I think so too. Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
pattern = re.compile(r'<ul id="talkList".*?(<li.*?</li>)', re.S)
```

Use

```
pattern = re.compile(r'<li.*?</li>', re.S)
```

Will solve your problem

Comment: In your case its matching for only one with your specified pattern of combination. If you matches with only common part, it will matches all occurrences of specified pattern @YOUNG

Comment: Thank! I know if change it to `pattern = re.compile(r'<li.*?</li>', re.S)` will match all <LI>, but I just  want to match the <LI>  **UNDER** this UL(` <ul id="talkList"`) .

Comment: you can still do that by specifying unique id to `<li>` which you want to list and include in `re.compile()` with `<li id="__" .*?</li>` @YOUNG

Comment: mention common `id` to `<li>` which you want to list @YOUNG

Comment: OK , I'm already sloved thanks